# Jogo da Velha, Função não funciona

Tags: javascript, html, funções

Me deparei com alguns problemas durante o projeto de criar um jogo da velha.
Resolvi todos com exceção deste: Minha função `VerificarVencedor()` não retorna nada, o as condições existem mas é como se não fossem respeitadas.

Pode me ajudar a entender?

```js
const player1 = "X";
const player2 = "O";
var playTime = player1;
var gameOver = false;

atualizarMostrador();
iniciarEspacos();

function atualizarMostrador() {
  if (gameOver) {
    return;
  }
  if (playTime == player1) {
    var player = document.querySelectorAll("div#mostrador img")[0];
    player.setAttribute("src", "imagens/x.png");
  } else {
    var player = document.querySelectorAll("div#mostrador img")[0];
    player.setAttribute("src", "imagens/o.png");
  }
}

function iniciarEspacos() {
  var espacos = document.getElementsByClassName("espaco");
  for (var i = 0; i < espacos.length; i++) {
    espacos[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      if (gameOver) {
        return;
      }
      if (this.getElementsByTagName("img").length == 0) {
        if (playTime == player1) {
          this.innerHTML = "<img src='imagens/x.png' height='70'>";
          this.setAttribute = ("jogada", player1);
          playTime = player2;
        } else {
          this.innerHTML = "<img src='imagens/o.png' height='50'>";
          this.setAttribute = ("jogada", player2);
          playTime = player1;
        }
        atualizarMostrador();
        verificarVencedor();
      }
    });
  }
}

function verificarVencedor() {
  var a1 = document.getElementById("a1").getAttribute("jogada");
  var a2 = document.getElementById("a2").getAttribute("jogada");
  var a3 = document.getElementById("a3").getAttribute("jogada");

  var b1 = document.getElementById("b1").getAttribute("jogada");
  var b2 = document.getElementById("b2").getAttribute("jogada");
  var b3 = document.getElementById("b3").getAttribute("jogada");

  var c1 = document.getElementById("c1").getAttribute("jogada");
  var c2 = document.getElementById("c2").getAttribute("jogada");
  var c3 = document.getElementById("c3").getAttribute("jogada");

  var vencedor = "";

  if (((a1 == b1 && a1 == c1) || (a1 == a2 && a1 == a3) || (a1 == b2 && a1 == c3)) && a1 != "") {
    vencedor = a1;
  } else if (((b2 == b1 && b2 == b3) || (b2 == a2 && b2 == c2) || (b2 == a3 && b2 == c1)) && b2 != "") {
    vencedor = b2;
  } else if (((c3 == c2 && c3 == c1) || (c3 == a3 && c3 == b3)) && c3 != "") {
    vencedor = c3;
  }
  if (vencedor != "") {
    gameOver = true;
    alert("O ganhador foi o:  '" + vencedor + " ' ");
  }

}
```

```css
#mostrador {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 252px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 0px;
}

.espaco {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

.tabuleiro {
  margin: auto;
  width: 252px;
  height: 252px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="pt-BR">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Jogo da Velha</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="mostrador">
    <p style="float: left; margin-right: 10px;">Vez do Jogador: </p>
    <img src="" border="0" height="50">
  </div>
  <div class="tabuleiro">
    <div id="a1" class="espaco" jogada=""> </div>
    <div id="a2" class="espaco" jogada=""> </div>
    <div id="a3" class="espaco" jogada=""> </div>

    <div id="b1" class="espaco" jogada=""> </div>
    <div id="b2" class="espaco" jogada=""> </div>
    <div id="b3" class="espaco" jogada=""> </div>

    <div id="c1" class="espaco" jogada=""> </div>
    <div id="c2" class="espaco" jogada=""> </div>
    <div id="c3" class="espaco" jogada=""> </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="game.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema na verdade não está na sua função `verificaVencedor()` e sim na sua função `iniciaEspacos()`.

Na linha em que você seta o atributo "jogada", você está cometendo um erro de sintaxe.

Antes de tudo é importante entender melhor os conceitos de **atribuir uma variável** e **invocar uma função**.

Quando você quer **atribuir um valor a uma variável** você utiliza a seguinte sintaxe:

```
variavelNome = variavelValor;
```

Já quando você quer **invocar uma função** a sintaxe é diferente:

```
funcaoNome(parametro1, parametro2)
```

O problema está aí, setAttribute é uma função e para obter o efeito desejado você deve **invocar essa função** com a sintaxe correta. No seu caso você está utilizando a sintaxe de **atribuir uma variável** na **função setAttribute()**.

Ou seja, o seu código correto deve ficar assim:

```
this.setAttribute('jogador', player1)
```

Além disso, é importante lembrar que atributos personalizados devem ser prefixados com o `data-`, pois esse é o padrão semanticamente correto para adicionar atributos que não existem por padrão no elemento, ou seja o seu código HTML deve ficar assim:

```
<div id="a1" class="espaco" data-jogada=""> </div>
```

E no JS para setar o atributo também deve mudar para:

```
this.setAttribute('data-jogada', player1);
```

Vou deixar aqui links da documentação, onde você pode obter as informações com mais detalhes:

- Sobre atribuição de variável: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types
- Sobre invocar uma função: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Call
- Sobre a função setAttribute: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute
- Sobre o prefixo para atributos `data-*`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes